# Headphones not working. Realtek ALC270. Asus K55VD-DS71 laptop. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, asus, alsa, headphones

I helping my friend to setup ubuntu who is a first time user. It's an ASUS K55VD-DS71 laptop.

Following codecs are  being reported on the system when I issue the command `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`

> Codec: Realtek ALC270
>   Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI`

Using the `ALSA information script v0.4.60` I have obtained information about my alsa setup and device which is [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d803ad0523fb069e9bdb7ead7dd39d56bccde362)

The interesting thing is that Pulse Audio sound settings reports only one device and that is Headphones (Build in Audio) BUT the sound comes only from speaker even if speakers are not listed there. There is no sound from the headphones.

I played around with `alsamixer` a bit and also `alsa-base.conf` a bit and once got the sound working from headphones but after restart the same problem as described above reappeared.

If I could get it to work once I believe there must be something really trivial which I am missing here. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

P.S : My friend is using Ubuntu for the first time so I am trying to make the transition from windows as smooth as possible. A non-working hardware especially headphones can be a major roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled and upgraded the system using upgrade manager. Everything worked.